# How to log the destinations transfering by the reverse proxy？

Tags: ibmhttpserver

I integrated Apache HTTP Server into IBM WebSphere, using a virtual ip as reverse proxy to transfer the request to some destination servers. But I found the log format providing by the HTTP Server can only log the information of request and the size of response. My purpose is to log the ip and ports of the object servers.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you only send requests to a single VIP, the proxy server cannot know what other names/addresses the origin servers might be using. You'd have to add such a header from your application.

If a HTTP session is established, you could log %{Set-Cookie}o and observe the WAS clone id for correlation.  Logging %{JSESSIONID}C would get you the clone ID in the request, when present.

This configuration is quite rare because it doesn't support session affinity. A more conventional config uses the WAS WebServer Plug-in, and you can simply log `%{WAS}e` to get the data you want.